# Replace function - SQL - Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, data, replace

I have a data extension with a column titled 'Email Name'. My reporting I have it pipe (`|`) delimited into a .txt file. When the 'Email Name' column comes in, some values have spaces in the front for example:    `Wow - this email is awesome|`.

I'm want to remove the space at the front of the Email Name for every value in the 'Email Name' column. The spaces always come after the | but before the name. Is there a way to do that utilizing the REPLACE function? Below is what I have, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```sql
Select  [Email Name], 
REPLACE([Email Name], '%Wow', 'Wow%')
as 'Wow%' 
From Data_Extension_Name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can likely use the **[TRIM()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_trim.asp)**, **[LTRIM()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_ltrim.asp)** or **[RTRIM()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_rtrim.asp)** functions.

I vaguely remember that the more general TRIM() does not work in SFMC, so in this case you would want to use LTRIM().

For example, say you have the following data:

```
col
--------
 Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
```

you would then use the following SQL to remove that space from Name 1:

```sql
SELECT LTRIM(col) AS Name
FROM myDE
```

Which will return:

```
Name
--------
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
```

To also remove trailing spaces, you can combine it to:

```sql
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(col)) AS Name
FROM myDE
```

This of course would be easier to be done by using TRIM() which does both, but as I stated, I do not believe it works in SFMC.